# Which build of gcc should I use to correctly build rustlearn crate?

Tags: windows, rust

I'm trying to use `rustlearn` crate in my project. Added the dependency in `Cargo.toml`.
Since `rustlearn` requires `gcc`, I downloaded and installed `MinGW64`.
I tried the following `gcc` builds:

- x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0
- x86_64-8.1.0-posix-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0
- i686-8.1.0-posix-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0

each time setting a `PATH` environment variable to the appropriate `g++.exe` and restarting VSCode.
But everytime I tried to build my Rust package I got a such error:

```
 = note: C:\Rust\PF\machinelearning\target\debug\deps\librustlearn-4ae611e3fd449ac0.rlib(svm.o): In function `ZN6KernelC2EiPKP8svm_nodeRK13svm_parameter':
          C:\Git-local-repos\rustlearn/dependencies/libsvm/svm.cpp:256: undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
          C:\Git-local-repos\rustlearn/dependencies/libsvm/svm.cpp:256: undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
          C:\Git-local-repos\rustlearn/dependencies/libsvm/svm.cpp:258: undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
          C:\Git-local-repos\rustlearn/dependencies/libsvm/svm.cpp:289: undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
```

repeated many times.
I realize that the problem is somehow related to exception handling (seh/sjlj).
My system is Windows 7 x86-64, rust toolchain is stable-i686-pc-windows-gnu.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Answers to the question should not be edited into the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the right build of MinGW is i686-7.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev2.

Answer (score 0):

I did not run into these errors when I created a MWE.

To me, this looks like you are trying to use `gcc` to link a *.o that was compiled with `g++`.

I was unable to replicate your problem. Here's what I did--which resulted in a successfully built project:

1. I created a new project with `cargo new` and added the following to `Cargo.toml`:

```
rustlearn = "0.5.0"
```

2. I ran `cargo check` to download all the required dependencies.
3. I edited `src/main.rs` to include the logistic regression example from [here](https://maciejkula.github.io/rustlearn/doc/rustlearn/), modified so that it was called in a `main()` function.
4. I ran `cargo build`, which successfully compiled `crossbeam`, `libc`, `serde`, `rand`, `rustlearn`, and `rustlearn-test`--the name of my test package. Several linting warnings were outputted; they were ignored.
5. I ran `cargo run`, which successfully ran the program.

FWIW, I'm using the WSL on Windows 10.